# Matlab - Display trailing edge of a long strings in a listbox by hovering the mouse over the string

Tags: string, matlab, user-interface, listbox, uicontrol

I have a Matlab listbox on which some strings are very long. I do not want to make listbox too wide just only because of these few long strings. 
Is there anyway to display trailing edge of these long strings in my listbox by simply hovering the mouse over those strings without using scroll pane?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See Jan's answer using Java objects. Worked great.

```
% Prepare the Matlab listbox uicontrol
hFig = figure;
listItems =   {'apple','orange','banana','lemon','cherry','pear','melon'};
hListbox = uicontrol(hFig, 'style','listbox', 'pos',[20,20,60,60],  'string',listItems);

% Get the listbox's underlying Java control
jScrollPane = findjobj(hListbox);

% We got the scrollpane container - get its actual contained listbox control
jListbox = jScrollPane.getViewport.getComponent(0);

% Convert to a callback-able reference handle
jListbox = handle(jListbox, 'CallbackProperties');
% Set the mouse-movement event callback
set(jListbox, 'MouseMovedCallback', {@mouseMovedCallback,hListbox});

% Mouse-movement callback
function mouseMovedCallback(jListbox, jEventData, hListbox)
% Get the currently-hovered list-item
mousePos = java.awt.Point(jEventData.getX, jEventData.getY);
hoverIndex = jListbox.locationToIndex(mousePos) + 1;
listValues = get(hListbox,'string');
hoverValue = listValues{hoverIndex};

% Modify the tooltip based on the hovered item
msgStr = sprintf('<html>item #%d: <b>%s</b></html>', hoverIndex, hoverValue);
set(hListbox, 'Tooltip',msgStr);
end  % mouseMovedCallback
```

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/436048-display-trailing-edge-of-a-long-strings-of-a-listbox-by-hovering-the-mouse-over-the-string#answer_352806

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can set the `TooltipString` property of your listbox. This is what is displayed when you hover the cursor on some object. It will not be a nice or user friendly but is better than nothing.

```
%Create a listbox
myListbox = uicontrol('Style','listbox');
set(myListbox,'TooltipString','','Callback',@listboxCB);

%Callback function called each time the listbox value is changed
%It should also be called whenever the 'String' property is updated
function listboxCB(obj,evt)
    %Get the value 
    v=get(obj,'Value');
    if isempty(v)
        set(myListbox,'TooltipString','');
        return;
    end
    %Get the string corresponding to that line
    str = get(obj,'String');
    str = str{v(1)};         %Show the first one (if 'multiselect' = 'on')
    set(myListbox,'TooltipString',str);
end
```

There may be some clever way by interacting directly with the underlying Java objects.